# JQuery accordion menu with nested accordion menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I'm putting together a series of nested accordion menus, but it seems that when I try to expand child menus, the parent menu will collapse, and then the behavior of the entire menu goes haywire. Worth noting is that I've commented out (line 37 of the CSS on JSFiddle) to at test some of the nested behaviors, but my intended state is for all parent menus to default to being closed.

My code:

```js
$('.product-title').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
var lastItem;
$('.product-title').click(function(currentItem) {
  var currentItem = $(this);
  if ($(this).next().height() == 0) {
    $(lastItem).css({
      'font-weight': 'normal'
    });
    $(lastItem).next().animate({
      height: '0px'
    }, 400, 'swing');
    $(this).css({
      'font-weight': 'bold'
    });
    $(this).next().animate({
      height: '100%',
      opacity: 1
    }, 400, 'swing');
  } else {
    $(this).next().animate({
      height: '0px',
      opacity: 1
    }, 400, 'swing');
  }
  lastItem = $(this);
});
$(function() {
  $('.product-title').click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('plus-KO minus-KO');
  });
});
$('.product-name').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
var lastItem;
$('.product-name').click(function(currentItem) {
  var currentItem = $(this);
  if ($(this).next().height() == 0) {
    $(lastItem).css({
      'font-weight': 'normal'
    });
    $(lastItem).next().animate({
      height: '0px'
    }, 400, 'swing');
    $(this).next().animate({
      height: '100%',
      opacity: 1
    }, 400, 'swing');
  } else {
    $(this).css({
      'font-weight': 'normal'
    });
    $(this).next().animate({
      height: '0px',
      opacity: 1
    }, 400, 'swing');
  }
  lastItem = $(this);
});
$(function() {
  $('.product-name').click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('plus minus');
  });
});
```

```css
.product {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-block {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.product-title {
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  background-color: #07457e;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 10px;
  border: solid 1px #07457e;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.product-name {
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #737373;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-title:hover {
  background-color: silver !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-name:hover {
  background-color: silver !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-section {
  display: block;
  /*height: 0px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-desc {
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #737373;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #07457e;
}

.product-desc p {
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.item-length {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-length p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.device-length {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-number {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-padding {
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-feature {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
}

.product-key {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.product-key p {
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
  color: #07457e;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 160%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.plus-KO:before {
  content: "+";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.minus-KO:before {
  content: "\2013";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.plus:before {
  content: "+";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #07457e;
}

.minus:before {
  content: "\2013";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #07457e;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* menu table visibility set by screen width */
  .device-length {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  /* menu table visibility set by screen width */
  .device-length {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-block">
    <div class="product-title"><i class="plus-KO"></i>&ensp;Product title</div>
    <div class="product-section">
      <div class="product-key">
        <p>Product subtitle</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-block">
    <div class="product-title"><i class="plus-KO"></i>&ensp;Product title</div>
    <div class="product-section">
      <div class="product-key">
        <p>roduct subtitle</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this at the beginning

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.product-section').css('height',0);
});`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.product-section').css('height',0);
});
$('.product-title').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
var lastItem;
    $('.product-title').click(function(currentItem) {
        var currentItem = $(this);
      if ($(this).next().height() == 0) {
          $(lastItem).css({'font-weight':'normal'});
          $(lastItem).next().animate({height: '0px'},400,'swing');
          $(this).css({'font-weight':'bold'});
          $(this).next().animate({height: '100%',opacity: 1},400,'swing');
      } else {
          $(this).next().animate({height: '0px',opacity: 1},400,'swing');
      }
      lastItem = $(this);
    });
$(function() {
    $('.product-title').click(function() {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('plus-KO minus-KO');
    });
});
$('.product-name').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
var lastItem;
    $('.product-name').click(function(currentItem) {
        var currentItem = $(this);
      if ($(this).next('.product-desc').height() == 0) {
          $(lastItem).css({'font-weight':'normal'});
          $(lastItem).next('.product-desc').animate({height: '0px'},400,'swing');
          $(this).next('.product-desc').animate({height: '100%',opacity: 1},400,'swing');
      } else {
          $(this).css({'font-weight':'normal'});
          $(this).next('.product-desc').animate({height: '0px',opacity: 1},400,'swing');
      }
      lastItem = $(this);
    });
$(function() {
    $('.product-name').click(function() {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('plus minus');
    });
});
```

```css
.product {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-block {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.product-title {
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  background-color: #07457e;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 10px;
  border: solid 1px #07457e;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.product-name {
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #737373;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-title:hover {
  background-color: silver !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-name:hover {
  background-color: silver !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-section {
  display: block;
  /*height: 0px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-desc {
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #737373;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #07457e;
}

.product-desc p {
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.item-length {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-length p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.device-length {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-number {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-padding {
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-feature {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
}

.product-key {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.product-key p {
  font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
  color: #07457e;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 160%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.plus-KO:before {
  content: "+";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.minus-KO:before {
  content: "\2013";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.plus:before {
  content: "+";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #07457e;
}

.minus:before {
  content: "\2013";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #07457e;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* menu table visibility set by screen width */
  .device-length {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  /* menu table visibility set by screen width */
  .device-length {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-block">
    <div class="product-title"><i class="plus-KO"></i>&ensp;Product title</div>
    <div class="product-section">
      <div class="product-key">
        <p>Product subtitle</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-block">
    <div class="product-title"><i class="plus-KO"></i>&ensp;Product title</div>
    <div class="product-section">
      <div class="product-key">
        <p>roduct subtitle</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-name"><i class="plus"></i>&ensp;Product name</div>
      <div class="product-desc">
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="device-length">
          <div class="item-padding">
            <div class="item-length">
              <p>Size</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item-number">
              <p>Item number</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Almost. What happens is when the parent menu expands, and I try to expand one of the child menus, the whole thing collapses in on itself. instead of expanding the child menu.

Comment: Corrected, check now

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use JQuery UI Accordion, here is how to do it:

Remove height: 0px from .product-section in css
Include jquery ui in your html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then use this javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $(".product-block").accordion({
        header:'.product-title',
    icons: {
                    header: "plus-KO",
                    activeHeader: "minus-KO"
    },
        heightStyle: 'content',
    collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
  $(".product-section").accordion({
        header:'.product-name',
    icons: {
                    header: "plus",
                    activeHeader: "minus"
    },
    heightStyle: 'content',
    collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
});
```

I removed the  icons from your html for the + - classes because jquery accordion provides icon-ing as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/jLqcoys2/

Comment: I love the solution, but my CMS can't link to the jquery ui to make it work correctly. Is there an alternative that can accommodate for that?

Comment: you can always download the jquery ui file and host on your environment.
I figured since you had this line <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> that you can connect to the cdn for libraries.

Comment: Wish i could. I actually just edited that out of my code, as the other jquery link is in my working HTML file to test, but is not needed in the final application. My CMS is pretty locked down, and I'm not able to link to additional scripts beyond what's already available (just jquery).

Comment: Yup... that's how it usually is

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Such is the life sometimes.